# Mimtproxy not able to get requests in app

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, reverse-engineering, mitmproxy

I am trying to see the request sent inside of the Target app using mimtproxy. When I open the app nothing is popping up but I know something is up since I can see the client connecting to the target backend. Is there anything I should do so I am able to see the requests being sent. Also I am not too familiar with this , but I have a feeling that target detects the mimtproxy and is blocking it because I am unable to login while I have it on.

Comment: what is platform of the target app (OS and OS version)? did you install fake root CA certificate into target platform? did you check tcp dump to see what stage connection gets broken at (cert , app data)? if platform is android then either use "Android 6" or rooted devices(smartphones or SBCs) which allows you to add system level certificate.

Comment: I was a Iphone XR 14.0. No I don't think I installed a fake root CA certificate into the target app. I installed the mimtproxy certifcate though. I am not familiar with a tcp dump . If it is that cli or the eventlog then I think it gets broken off when I try to authenticate through the app.

Comment: A lot of apps (including Apple apps and the Apple login) are performing certificate pinning. Therefore they don't trust the mitm certificate and no connection can be established. On a jailbroken phone you could try to connect to the app using Frida and use one of the anti-certificate-pinning scripts to bypass certificate pinning.